# typescript - how to extend an interface at a specific location (extend a base state for library xstate)

Tags: typescript, interface, xstate

I want to be able to extend a base interface at one or more specic locations. The idea is to be able to define a base state for the library xstate which can be extended for more specific purposes.

I have

```js
interface Base {
   id:string;
   states:{
       init:{},
       loading:{},
       idle:{
            states:{
                  someBaseState:{}
            }

       }
   }
}
```

I want to know if it is possible with typescript to extend the base interface at a specific location. e.g the "idle" property

```js
interface Page "extends Base Idle Property" {
   id:string;
   states:{
       someOtherState:{}
   }
}
```

so that the result is

```js
{
   id:string;
   states:{
       init:{},
       loading:{},
       idle:{
            id:string;
            states:{
                someBaseState:{}
                someOtherState:{}
            }
       }
   }
}
```

I know that I can define Generic in Typescript like this

```js
interface Base<T> {
  id: string;
  states: {
    idle: T
  }
}
```

But I want to be able to define specific base properties for the state "idle" (for example) and not completely implement it each time.

Comment: I don't see how you'd expect to combine `Base` and `Page` to yield your desired output, since `someOtherState` appears to be nested four levels down in your desired output but only two levels down in `Page`.  Could you please make sure that all your code constitutes a [mcve] so that someone could suggest a reasonable answer?  My guess in cases like this would be to use something like generics or an intersection instead of inheritance, but without understanding your question I wouldn't want to begin to develop an answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Given these definitions:

```
interface Base {
  id: string;
  states: {
    init: {};
    loading: {};
    idle: {
      states: {
        someBaseState: {};
      };
    };
  };
}

interface Page {
  id: string;
  states: {
    someOtherState: {};
  };
}
```

the easiest thing to do might be to use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) instead of inheritance, like this:

```
type MyNewType = Base & { states: { idle: Page } };
interface MyNewInterface extends MyNewType {} // if you want in interface
```

You can see it conforms to the shape you want:

```
function foo(mni: MyNewInterface) {
    mni.states.init; // okay
    mni.states.idle.id; // okay
    mni.states.idle.states.someBaseState; // okay
    mni.states.idle.states.someOtherState; // okay
}
```

That type might be a bit difficult to understand as an intesection... if you really want to you can use a nested [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like this:

```
type NestedId<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: NestedId<T[K]> } : T;
type NestedExtend<T, U> = NestedId<T & U>;

type MyNewType2 = NestedExtend<Base, { states: { idle: Page } }>;
```

which shows you the following type when you inspect via IntelliSense:

```
// IntelliSense shows you
type MyNewType2 = {
    id: string;
    states: {
        init: {};
        loading: {};
        idle: {
            states: {
                someBaseState: {};
                someOtherState: {};
            };
            id: string;
        };
    };
}
```

Either way should work.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMhmFKAOYDc+5YckGZeBBowYbAvvR2QAbAPZwiNPgI7EhENg0EVmEVsnaCOGEQFsI6LAGUmkKYo79zlgpd65coSLEQoACnGo4GxMhSog6BmUWBSVdCAB5MAALaGMVMxt6O1wwAE8ABxQAWTSAOQgAdwAVTJQAXjRMFAAydUYVNWxCIjkyd09kXi76R2h4JGRcgsKASXB+l2QIAA9IECIMIfyi0qz1OxgAVxAEMGAREGQYEREACh0QYDJhovGnAYgASnVzS+AAOmDVD64wWmQAHpAcgRABrOBpN5XL4mH6yCC-IgA4GgiFQwTvWGNJFybEsL7hAwQeKQFEg8GQ6Gfb4YXGI2mEvRRWJQUkQcloqkpVJlZAFCgQIijIgAHmKAD5kJVitM5hAFksRAAjABWED2yAA-PUANoAaUIRzBEDSIhgyGKAF0yALIMKxcUDVapd0yMV6Ol1nahQBReULcUAGmQAFUpZUfQ7xcg6uH6Lz1rcSmUAEzS-mqe3++Zi4kh5q0tgtNrIDoobq8CUJwEAKlwqPuECEQmAhgVWHI0REhSWZq2iZyKxTWXTlQ0nFIjH8gSUcKa5kEf0SmgIonEkg20lXCNCq80Rde++P5CJ1XZK5PB-CLLicMvJ+sV5avkoNG3mifSVwdlrgPsQA)